# Using Cypress how to run a pre-test code on 1 domain before executing all tests on another domain

Tags: cypress

I have the following use case. There are two sites on different domains. usersettings.com (written in ExtJS) and myapp.com (angular app). Usersettings.com contains configurations that would alter the UI of myapp.com. Please see the screenshot for example.

[image: cypress use case]

Now since I need to modify user-settings to different ones before running all the test files. What would be the best approach to solve this use case in Cypress.

One approach I am planning to use is a single Cypress spec file to visit usersettings.com and alter the configuration of the user-settings site. I can achieve it by coding it as a support file. Post that, I can run my entire test suite (having multiple *.spec.js files). The question is it possible and is it a good approach against other alternatives (if any)?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by setting up the test in a separate test case

```
//Global setup

context('doubleDomainTest', () => {
    it('firstDomain', function () {
        //Code to run on the firstDomain
    })
    it('secondDomain', function () {
        //Code to run on the secondDomain
    })
})
```

Comment: Sorry for the naive question, but how do I make this global test case run before the entire test suite begins?

Comment: For such cases I do a custom command and use it when needed, because I can not know if there will be a case when it is not needed. Like this it is easy to maintain as well. This is the best coding practice according to mi seniors - do not make global settings unless absolutely needed. 

In theory - if you want - you should be able to put a `before()` case in the `/support/index.js` that will be run before every test, but I do not recommend it.